# How to Integrate Autofac and Log4Net with ASP.NET Web API 2 Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, autofac, asp.net-mvc-5

I have been moving in circles for the last few hours trying to integrate Autofac and ASP.NET Web API 2 Application. I have been following the [Autofac](http://autofac.org/) and and its wiki at [Integrating with ASP.NET Web API](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/WebApiIntegration).

But clearly, this wiki is outdated for Web API 2. Does anyone have a way i could configure my application to work with Autofac? I am just about giving up and going back to Ninject.

I have installed [Autofac](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac/), [Autofac.WebApi2](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.WebApi2/) and [Autofac.Mvc5](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Mvc5/)

**I can't call the following**

`containerBuilder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());`

`.InstancePerApiRequest();` not reachable. In fact, anything i try to call with Api in the name is not defined. (Such as `RegisterApiControllers, AsWebApiActionFilterFor, RegisterWebApiFilterProvider, InstancePerApiRequest, InstancePerApiControllerType`)

Also, i am trying to use Log4Net and i have implemented the Module as per wiki, now in the LoggingActionFilter shown in the wiki, what do i replace this line with as Log4Net does not contain a definition for `Write`

`_logger.Write(actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [Autofac.WebApi5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.WebApi5/) nuget (be sure to use the syntax for installing the release candidate package) instead of the Autofac.WebApi2 package. Then initialize it using code like this in Global.asax.cs:

```
IocContainer container = // code to create your container
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = 
    new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```

This setup is working for me on an MVC5/API2 project.

Comment: It really doesn't make a difference. What i need is an updated wiki or instructions that works with web api 2

Comment: @KomengeMwandila According to alexmg (creator of autofac), the WebApi5 nuget is [the one to use](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/autofac/ASmqK4TzEos/PjY837sjdDQJ). You can read more about the web api packages in [these](http://alexmg.com/new-features-in-the-autofac-mvc-4-and-web-api-beta-integrations/) [two](http://alexmg.com/autofac-262859-and-aspnet-mvc-4-rc-integrations-released/) blog posts. The above setup in my answer is working for me. What is happening when you try it? Can you post code or error messages?

Comment: Looks like everything will work now, for some reason i wasn't getting `Autofac.Integration.WebApi;` namespace. Also, note that Web API 2 is the latest package compared to web api 5 package you mentioned. I compared the release dates.

Comment: Worked for me when .NET could not find GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.  Thanks! +1